Flutter - Redirection after clicking on deeplink not working despite getting the token
I'm struggling to make a redirection to my page for reinitializing a forgotten password.
i have a website, having the link "com-example-app://reinitialiser_mdp/token=dda8f861-fd89-492f-8d55-bf85e27743b0" on it (just for testing), and i want to redirect the user to the ReinitialisationPage, only if he click on a link that is valid and that contain a token (that is pre stored in my db).
but this code only open the app on the login page, despite having the token printed out :
Reloaded 14 of 1149 libraries in 1 410ms (compile: 172 ms, reload: 458 ms, reassemble: 568 ms).
I/flutter (18156): Received uri host: reinitialiser_mdp
I/flutter (18156): token : dda8f861-fd89-492f-8d55-bf85e27743b0

here is the main.dart :
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => UserProvider(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? _token;
  StreamSubscription<String?>? _linkSubscription;
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
     _linkSubscription = linkStream.listen((String? linkStr) {
            if (linkStr != null) {
              Uri linkUri = Uri.parse(linkStr);
              print('Received uri host: ${linkUri.host}');
              if (linkUri.host == 'reinitialiser_mdp') {
                final tokenUri = linkUri.queryParameters['token'];
                if (tokenUri != null) {
                  print('token : $tokenUri');
                  setState(() {
                    _token = tokenUri;
                  });
                } else {
                  _token = null;
                }
              }
            }
          });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _linkSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(primary: const Color(0xFF008EFE)),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: _token == null ? _buildHomePage() : ReinitialiserMdpPage(token: _token),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHomePage() {
    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

    if (userProvider.user == null) {
      return const MyLoginPage();
    } else {
      return const MyHomePage();
    }
  }
}

and the reiMdp.dart :

void main() {
   runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => UserProvider(),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(primary: const Color(0xFF008EFE)),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const ReinitialiserMdpPage(),
    );
  }
}


class ReinitialiserMdpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? token;
  const ReinitialiserMdpPage({super.key, this.token});


  @override
  ReinitialiserMdpPageState createState() => ReinitialiserMdpPageState();
}

class ReinitialiserMdpPageState extends State<ReinitialiserMdpPage> {
  late String? token;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    token = widget.token;
  }

  Future<bool> checkIfTokenInDB(token) async {
    if(token == null) {
      return false;
    }
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('${ApiConfig.baseUrl}/token/ifTokenInDb/$token'));
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      if(response.body == 'true') {
        print('token dans la bdd');
        return true;
      } else {
        print('token pas trouvé dans la bdd');
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Erreur de chargement');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Page de réinitialisation du mot de passe'),
          Text('Token: $token'),
        ],
      ),
    );
    
  }
}

i tried a lot of thing but even chatgpt doesn't know what to do.

In the 'build' method of main.dart, print the _token and check the value of it. The code would be: print(_token) and it should go between 'Widget build(BuildContext context) {' and 'return MaterialApp('

it just print the token like it should be, but it doesnt open the reinitialisationPage everytime ? like if i just do a 'run without debbuging' on vscode, it first open the reinitialisationPage with 'null' printed out, but if i click the link a second time, everyhting run normaly, but if i click on another link with another token it doesnt take the new token and just keep the first one. also if i open the app by clicking on the icon of my android phone, it just open it on the reinitialisationPage with the same token.
